# Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS how to avoid windows going off the current workspace

Tags: 12.04, compiz, window-manager

Sometimes open windows go out of the bound of the current workspace without any keyboard shortcut used and it is very annoying since the title bar may be inaccessible at times. I have Compiz installed but really do not know how to configure it properly to achieve the desired effect. I would appreciate some help on the matter.

Thanks

P.S: I am very fond of the windows snap feature and use it occasionally.

Answer (score 2):

Press and hold Alt button, then click on anywhere in the windows to drag it. You don't need to click on title bar to drag the window.

Comment: That is a workaround, but isn't there the option to completely inhibit windows from invading other workspaces when dragged with the mouse?

Comment: I suspect there is a way to do so. Compiz has been deserted for quite some time. If you check the compiz ppa, you will see there is very little improvement in recent years